# One RecyclerAdapter for two activity

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, adapter

I make app with a couple of different categories of pictures. I want to display those pictures with RecyclerView.

I want to display button as a image when I clicked button before. 
Can I make it in one adapter? Now I have two adapters, that code is as follow:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private int[] images = {
   R.drawable.imageA1, ....    R.drawable.imageA10
};
private int[] images2 = {
        R.drawable.imageB1, ....    R.drawable.imageB10
  };

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public int currentItem;
    public ImageView itemImage, itemImage2;
    public TextView itemTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.article_layout, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
     }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.length;
}
```

}

Comment: At the end I made it with creation separate adapter for each new activity which starts when user click buttons in my start activity. Than everybody who made comment below and proposed the solution. When I got more experience I will make it with one adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass images array dynamically to your adapter as below

```
private int[] images = {
   R.drawable.imageA1, ....    R.drawable.imageA10
};
private int[] images2 = {
        R.drawable.imageB1, ....    R.drawable.imageB10
  };
```

on click of button A

```
RecyclerAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(images)
yourRecyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter )
```

on click of button B

```
RecyclerAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(images2)
yourRecyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter )
```

change in your adapter as following

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private int[] images = new int[];

public RecyclerAdapter(int[] imgs){
images = imgs;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public int currentItem;
    public ImageView itemImage, itemImage2;
    public TextView itemTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.article_layout, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
     }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.length;
}
}
```

Comment: why setting adapter on each click?

Comment: @Eswar as Pawel said he wants to open list in different activity in above comment

Answer (score 1):

You can set method in adapter that you will call when users clicks button:

```
// for button A
public void setImages() { 
  this.showImages = true;
}

// for button B
public void setImages2() {
  this.showImages = false;
}
```

Then modify your on bind method to bind appropriate images:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    if (this.showImages)
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
    else
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Why should he do this? Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: He wants toggle functionality in one adapter. I just showed him one way he can accomplish it with simple if-else and boolean. Example that he can do it in single adapter.

Comment: Of course I totally agree, the syntax is perfect. I was thinking more of the information provided for both the OP/future users.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gudin
In my StartActivity I have two buttons to choose, and when user clicks one I open different activity for each action:
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.imageButton1:
    Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ActivityOne.class);
    startActivity(newActivity1);
    break;
   case R.id.imageButton2:
    Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
    startActivity(newActivity2);
    break;
How shoudl I correlate this with recycler appropiate image source?

Comment: @Pawel in that case. When you set adapter from ActivityOne use adapter.setImages() after you initialize adapter. From ActivityTwo use adapter.setImages2().

Comment: It just give me an idea that I don't need two new activities but only one with differnt image resources used to display from adapter. Will try to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I always get "last" viewHolder results in any activity. When in onBindViewHolder the last is  viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images2[i]); I display imagest2 for all activities, if the last is  viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]); I display images for all activities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible. make constructor in adpater like that:

```
 public  RecyclerAdapter(Context context,int[] images)
{
    this.diff_images=images;
    this.context=context;

}
```

the diff_images is also int array in adapter class. 
and make images array in your activity class. when you press button one then pass image1 array in adpater and if when press button2 then pass image2 array (if your want to show same view for both cases and if you want to show different view for both images)
if your adapter already set like:

```
    recycleViewAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, imageArray);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapter);
```

then you can also make one more method in adapter class and only notify adapter for update image

```
  public void setNewImageList(Context context, int[] imageArray) {
    this.context = context;
    this.diff_images = imageArray;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

try this.